# Best way to be friends with people at work in a new country

Tags: colleagues, socializing

How can I get more involved with people at work? I wouldn't want to come off as desperate of course and I am not. However, I feel it is important to do it here especially since I anyway know very few people outside of work.

Comment: How many times have you invited some of them for drinks after work? If you are just hanging around, waiting to be invited, that may be the problem. Take action yourself.

Comment: I believe Making a small chat is a part of trying :) I have been doing that all along. I don't usually host parties so haven't invited anyone. Besides I am new here to the country so I am not sure I know how things work here and if I should expect people to come at all even if I do invite

Comment: Small talk is just that. The golden rule of being invited out is to invite people out yourself, so that's it. Maybe someone can pat that into a few paragraphs worth of an answer.

Comment: just talk to them about the food or movie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how large your organization is! If it is a larger one, chances are that there is something organized (at least in germany this is true) like doing sports together. If so I'd say this would be the best place to engage in, because this would give you the opportunity to spend time away from work the work context with your people. If the organization is quite small this might not be possible. But on the other side in smaller organizations it should be more easy to get in contact by inviting to drinks afterwork or make appointments for lunchtime.